# Epicor Prophet 21 add Document Link in Order

Tags: api, interactive, prophet, epicor

I need to add a document link in an order in Epicor Prophet 21 through the Interactive API, I think this is the way. In the usage example it only shows how to modify the fields of an "Address" but there are no examples of how to add a new entry in the list of the "Document Links" tab.

Has anyone had to do this and could you help me?

Through the interactive API I can create a session, but I can't find a way to add a document link in an order.